# "one" or "that" replacing a previously mentioned entity

Tags: pronouns

I'm wondering whether "one" or "that" should be used in the following. What's the difference?

An apartment in this area is much more expensive than **one**/**that** in downtown Boston.

Comment: **Than that** would imply that there is only one apartment in downtown Boston.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance, you have to use "one". As you probably already know, "one" stands for a duplicate of the thing being compared. So in this sentence...

> An apartment in this area is much more expensive than [one][an
> apartment] in downtown Boston.

... you could say either "one" or "an apartment" and it would mean the same thing.

The word "that" can do the same sort of thing, but it *only* works when it stands for something that has a definite article. Furthermore, it usually works best in the two-word combination "that of". For example:

> The air quality in this city is better than that of Boston.

In this sentence, "that of Boston" means the same thing as "the air quality in/of Boston". Note the definite article. You could also say "... better than that in Boston," and people would understand you, but it wouldn't sound nearly as idiomatic. You couldn't say "... better than one in Boston" in this instance, because that would suggest that there is *more* than one air quality in Boston (just like there is more than one apartment), but air quality is uncountable, so that doesn't really make sense.

Here's a final example:

> There aren't any baseball stadiums in this city that are as nice as the one in Boston.

Here, "the one" works best. Using "the one" suggests that there is only one baseball stadium in Boston, or, if there are more than one, it is somehow clear from context which stadium in Boston is being referred to (it seems fairly obvious here that the reference is to the very famous Fenway Park, where the Red Sox play). You could also probably get away with saying "that of Boston," but "that of" doesn't sound as good (in my opinion) when the noun is countable, as is the case for "stadium".

Comment: Do you think "that" doesn't sound very idiomatic in "**The** apartment in this area is much more expensive than **that** in downtown Boston?

Comment: First, a problem: when you say "the apartment in this area" without context, you suggest that there is only one apartment in the area, because of the "the." Then you say "that in" downtown Boston, suggesting there is only one apartment there, too. But let's make sense of this by supposing that the person speaking owns two apartments - one here, and one in downtown Boston - and it's clear that these are the two apartments he is talking about. In that case, the sentence makes sense, but "that in Boston" does not sound nearly as good or idiomatic as "the one in Boston".

Comment: Is this okay? "The city council of Boston is more efficient than **that** of Bangkok"?

Comment: Yeah, basically, though you'd probably start with "Boston's city council" instead. The rest is good - you can use "of Bangkok" even if you didn't use "of Boston". Although you could also just say "... more efficient than Bangkok's."