# that vs possessive 's

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

I think both "that" and " possessive 's" are correct. But which is better style and why? I learned that being concise is considered better style. The possessive 's is more concise and so better?

> The system in Paris opened in 1900 and **Tokyo’s** opened in 1927.

> The system in Paris opened in 1900 and **that in Tokyo** opened in
> 1927.

> Compared with the two networks mentioned above, **Washington DC's** is
> relatively long, at 126 kilometers.

> Compared with the two networks mentioned above, **that in Washington
> DC** is relatively long, at 126 kilometers.

Comment: This is really an opinion-based question. However, the first one reads oddly because there is no corresponding possessive in the first half of the sentence.

Comment: Tokyo's/DC's sounds a lot more idiomatic to me (in the US). I also think I like "that of" better than "that in," though I don't have particularly strong feelings there. More on the topic: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/304050/142351

Comment: I am not familiar with how you are using *that*.  This does not appear correct.  Do you have any type of support for why you think *The system in Paris opened in 1900 and **that** in Tokyo opened in 1927.*  Your usage of *that* is not idiomatic.  It refers to *the System in Paris*.  I am assuming the system in Paris did not open in Tokyo, ever, seeing how it was in Paris.  In AmE, we would say *the one* in D.C.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther, I don't have any support for why I think "that" is correct. I just thought it were correct. I edited my question.

Comment: What do you mean by **at 126 kilometers** ?

Comment: @Sam, I mean D.C's subway is 126 kilometers long. I made up the number.

Comment: @Sam When you compare dimensions or weights, the preposition "at" can be used. The lightweight boxer came in at 125 pounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system in Paris opened in 1900 and Tokyo’s [system] opened in 1927.

The second system is implied.

*This is common usage, especially in spoken English.*

OR

The system in Paris opened in 1900 and *the one in Tokyo* opened in 1927.

[*formal, written usage*]

Same thing here:
Compared with the two networks mentioned above, Washington DC's is relatively long, at 126 kilometers.

Compared with the two networks mentioned above, *the one in* Washington DC is relatively long, at 126 kilometers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I found this sentence in an answer to an older question: The air quality in this city is better than that of Boston. I think it has almost the same structure as my first pair of sentences. That's to say, I can say "that of Tokyo"?

Comment: @Learner110 Yes, ok. So, you *could* use: The system in Paris opened in 1900 and that of Tokyo opened in 1927. But it sounds so ugly here. "the one" is much smoother.

Comment: Thank you, why does "that of Tokyo" sound so ugly but "that of Boston" doesn't?

Comment: @Learner110 I can't tell you exactly. Maybe because there are not two sentences with an "and".

Comment: @Learner110 - It is important to remember that possession in the phrase *that of Tokyo* is indicated by the use of the word **of**.  The word **that** plays no part in indicating possession, not in this instance, not in any instance.  *Those are the shoes **of** Robert.  Those are **Robert's** shoes.*

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther  You are very mistaken: **The system in Paris opened in 1900 and of Tokyo opened in 1927**. makes zero sense without **that of**.

Comment: @Lambie - That is true it makes no sense without it but **that** is not indicating possession. **That** is indicating we are talking about **systems**. *The system in Paris opened in 1900 and **that [system] of Tokyo opened in 1927*** .  Someday you'll catch me in an error.  I do make them.  Keep at it.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther No one said it did. that of Tokyo just means the one in Tokyo. And the OP was not confused about that anyway.